# Where invokeMethod in groovy is implemented?

Tags: java, groovy

I am reading  a book "Programming Groovy 2 by Venkat Subramaniam"  , in that book under 12'th chapter [Intercepting Methods Using MOP] he has given that *"If a Groovy object implements the GroovyInterceptable interface, then its invokeMethod() is
called for all its method calls."* . I tested this one and its working . My question here if I implement invokeMethod() on that class then it will be called otherwise default invokeMethod is called but by default invokeMethod() is not present in my class which implements GroovyInterceptable interface then how come this concept is working.

class with GroovyInterceptable interface implemeted

```
   class InterceptingMethodsUsingGroovyInterceptableExample {   
static void main(String... args){
    Phone phone = new Phone()
      phone.mobileNumber = 9755055420
    phone.mobileType = "Android"
    println phone.save()    

    Phone phone2 = new Phone()
    phone2.mobileNumber = 9755055420
    //phone2.mobileType = "Android"
    println phone2.save()

    Phone phone3 = new Phone()
    phone3.mobileNumber = 9755055420
    println phone3.isValid()    
    }   
      }

class Phone implements GroovyInterceptable {    
String mobileType;
Long mobileNumber   
def isValid(){
    def returnValue = false

    if ((mobileType)&& (mobileNumber?.toString()?.length() == 10) )
      returnValue = true

    returnValue
}

def save(){
    return "Saved"
}

 }

Output :
 Saved
 Saved
 false
```

JAD decompiled Code of Phone :

```
 public class Phone   implements GroovyInterceptable{
private String mobileType;
private Long mobileNumber;

public Phone()
{
    Phone this;
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
    MetaClass localMetaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();
    this.metaClass = localMetaClass;
}

public Object isValid()
{
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();Object returnValue = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    boolean bool1;
    boolean bool2;
    if ((!BytecodeInterface8.isOrigInt()) || (!BytecodeInterface8.isOrigZ()) || (__$stMC) || (BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass()))
    {
        if (((DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(this.mobileType)) && (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(arrayOfCallSite[0].callSafe(arrayOfCallSite[1].callSafe(this.mobileNumber)), Integer.valueOf(10))) ? 1 : 0) != 0)
        {
            bool1 = true;returnValue = Boolean.valueOf(bool1);
        }
    }
    else if (((DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(this.mobileType)) && (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(arrayOfCallSite[2].callSafe(arrayOfCallSite[3].callSafe(this.mobileNumber)), Integer.valueOf(10))) ? 1 : 0) != 0)
    {
        bool2 = true;returnValue = Boolean.valueOf(bool2);
    }
    return returnValue;return null;
}

public Object save()
{
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();return "Saved";return null;
}

static {}

public String getMobileType()
{
    return this.mobileType;
}

public void setMobileType(String paramString)
{
    this.mobileType = paramString;
}

public Long getMobileNumber()
{
    return this.mobileNumber;
}

public void setMobileNumber(Long paramLong)
{
    this.mobileNumber = paramLong;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for but maybe this will help.  There are places in the Groovy runtime where we interrogate an object at method invocation time to see if it implements GroovyInterceptable and then respond accordingly.  For example, in InvokerHelper there is code like this:

```
static Object invokePogoMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object arguments) {
    GroovyObject groovy = (GroovyObject) object;
    boolean intercepting = groovy instanceof GroovyInterceptable;
    try {
        // if it's a pure interceptable object (even intercepting toString(), clone(), ...)
        if (intercepting) {
            return groovy.invokeMethod(methodName, asUnwrappedArray(arguments));
        }
        //else try a statically typed method or a GDK method
        return groovy.getMetaClass().invokeMethod(object, methodName, asArray(arguments));
    } catch (MissingMethodException e) {
        if (e instanceof MissingMethodExecutionFailed) {
            throw (MissingMethodException) e.getCause();
        } else if (!intercepting && e.getMethod().equals(methodName) && object.getClass() == e.getType()) {
            // in case there's nothing else, invoke the object's own invokeMethod()
            return groovy.invokeMethod(methodName, asUnwrappedArray(arguments));
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

See [the source code here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/afba25576be408eefb92457de8c8aa0dc12c8061/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerHelper.java#L892).

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

If your class implements GroovyInterceptable, then whenever a method is invoked from a class that extend from your class, invokeMethod will be called.

```
class MyInterceptor implements GroovyInterceptable {

    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        println "Called everytime a method is invoked."
    }
}

class Example extends MyInterceptor {

    void someMethod() {

        print "Prints something"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default a groovy object has an implementation of the GroovyObject interface and hence an implementation of the invokeMethod method which is defined in that interface. That would explain why your code works even though you have not implemented the invokeMethod method in the Phone class.